# How to distribute a custom Ohai plugin

Tags: chef-infra

I'm writing an Ohai plugin to add some custom attributes to be used by the chef-client. Where do I include the plugin.rb file?

Is it inside the cookbook?

Or do I have to copy it to some standard place?

Chef docs and other tutorials don't offer much on this information (or I must have missed a huge obvious fact). I know in Puppet you can include the custom facts in lib/facter/ folder of the module. Is it the same in chef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not as hard as it sounds but I agree that the documentation on [Ohai 7](http://docs.getchef.com/ohai_custom.html) lacks the bit of information that was present in the [Ohai 6 docs](http://docs.getchef.com/release/ohai-6/).

However, the [`ohai` resource](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_ohai.html) and the [*ohai* cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ohai) are what you are looking for. An example of using that can be found in a [recipe of mine](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/openvz/blob/8204d6a53a6586fb8a4c6ea159e85fff3fe32c2f/recipes/ohai.rb#L71-L89).

Basically, you first have to put the plugin's `.rb` file into Ohai's plugin path (`node[:ohai][:plugin_path]`) and then reload Ohai in order to make the attributes available in the current chef run:

```rb
ohai "reload" do
  action :reload
end

template "#{node[:ohai][:plugin_path]}/myplugin.rb" do
  notifies :reload, "ohai[reload]"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I came across the old documentation after some searching and added the plugin file to the ohai cookbook. Still couldn't verify the functionality because of some infrastructure problems. Was waiting till the verification to post a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

For all the time the workflow of using custom ohai plugins changed many times. That's chef. This is normal for chef!

First ensure that you are using latest ohai cookbook (currently 5.2.0)

If you use chef-server you can does this as follows:

```
knife cookbook site download ohai
cd ~/you/cookbooks/folder
tar xzf ohai-5.2.0.tar.gz
rm ohai-5.2.0.tar.gz
knife cookbook upload ohai
```

On the official [site](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai) there is no cases how to use custom plugins.

Suppose you already have a plugin (ohai version 7) to deploy.

Include it in any application/wrapper cookbook you want following recipe:

```
ohai_plugin 'myplugin_status_ohai_plugin'
```

And puts in you application/wrapper cookbook a file with you plugin code in `files/default/myplugin_status_ohai_plugin.rb`. And that's all. By default you plugin will be installed to a directory named 'plugins' under the directory 'ohai' in the Chef config dir. Install and plugin collecting data function will be triggered at compile time.

If you do not specify `/etc/chef/ohai/plugins` as additional path in chef-client configuration is will be warn. But `/etc/chef/ohai/plugins` will be used by default.

To get rid of warning, use `chef-client` cookbook, recipe `chef-client::config`, node variable `node['ohai']['plugin_path']` as additional path to load Ohai plugins from.